# CSS Color overlay with blending mode multiply

Tags: css, sprite, effects

Is there any way to multiply image by color with respect to alpha channel like FX in Photoshop?
For example I have black&white&transparency button and I want to make it 4 different colors + 4 colors for hover state.

If it was glsl shader I would simply multiply each pixel by vertex color.

Here is button sprite:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4j43vf8l50mifw1/common_button_map_menu.png

Answer (score 0):

There is limited support for blend modes on CSS background images in browsers now. Try setting your background to a solid colour and using on a background-image with:

```
background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

IE won't play ball and Safari implementation is incomplete http://caniuse.com/#search=blend-mode

Comment: But pixels under transparent pixels of button(set as bg) will be multiplied too. So if I have let's say a photo and a div (with button+color as bg) floating over that photo there will be problem. The transparent pixels of button won't mask bg color and it will multiply underlying photo.